# Solrj JSON-facets

Tags: java, json, solrj, facet

I want to retrieve a JSON-facet using Solrj, I tried the code below, but I am not getting the facet.

```
    SolrClient solr = new HttpSolrClient.Builder(urlString).build();
    SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
    //parameters
    query.setQuery("*:*");
    query.setFields("module", "instanceId", "docType");
    query.add("json.facet","module_facet:{type:terms,field:module,facet:{doctype_facet:{type:terms,field:docType}}}");

    QueryResponse response = solr.query(query);     

    SolrDocumentList results  = response.getResults();

    //print
    for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); ++i) 
        System.out.println(results.get(i));
```

How should I retrieve the nested JSON-facet for the code below?

```
    query.add("json.facet","module_facet:{type:terms,field:module,facet:{doctype_facet:{type:terms,field:docType}}}");
```

Comment: I'm in the same boat. The facets are inside response.getResponse().get("facets") but solrj does not provide any model

Answer (score 0):

As of verson 7.7.0 there is the `QueryResponse#getJsonFacetingResponse()` method, which returns the json facets.